# How can I force "Open With" in the context menu to skip directly to browsing for a program file

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

When opening a file of an unknown type Win 7 will first offer to use the web service to search for a program. I find this screen useless and would like to skip it. After I select to use an installed program to open a file, Win 7 presents a list of installed programs which nine times out of ten doesn't show an appropriate program and is also useless.

How can I automatically skip the "use the web service" offer?

How can I either edit what programs appear on the installed programs menu or force Windows to skip directly to browsing for the program's executable?

I'd prefer registry hacks or altering system files to using a third-party program.

Comment: I have used SendTo to solve this, But now I hear it can't have sub menus in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the following registry key in Windows registry (You can type `regedit.exe` in the start menu search bar to open it):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
```

Now right click anywhere in the right pane and create a new 32-bit DWORD value with the following parameters:

- Name: `NoInternetOpenWith`
- Value: `1`

Close the registry editor for the changes to take effect. Now, whenever you try to open a file with no associated program, Windows 7 will skip the web service prompt and directly open the "Open With..." window.

[image]

Comment: You sir are my hero. I'm going to see if I can get an answer to the second half of the question before I accept anything, but even this much will save me a good deal of frustration.